# How to drag an object in any side of the 2D canvas with everything inside in it

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

I am having little difficulty here. working on 2D canvas and I can create rectangle with dragging mouse button in 2D canvas with four corner angles. This rectangle is flexible and can move in any direction with dragging mouse.

This rectangle should look like exactly same what I have in Image1, no matter where I am moving it. It looks perfect when I create this rectangle from top to bottom by dragging mouse but when I turn this to left side, you can see Image2, corner angles is outside of the box and weird. This same happens when I move cursor to upper side, see Image3.

I want this rectangle look like Image1 in every side. Please can anybody help me, how to fix this?

[image: Desired Image. No matter which side mouse cursor point is.]
Image1 - Desired Image. No matter which side mouse cursor point is.

[image]
Image2 - When I move mouse point Left side of canvas

[image]
Image3 - When I move mouse point Upper side of canvas

```
 function drawBox(x, y, w, h, crosshairSize, detailWidth, fill, detailCol) {
        ctx.globalAlpha = 0.3;
        function drawCross(x, y, s, w) { // draw crosshair s is size, w is width
           const hw = w / 2; // half width
           ctx.beginPath();
           ctx.lineTo(x - hw, y - hw);
           ctx.lineTo(x - hw, y - s);
           ctx.lineTo(x + hw, y - s);
           ctx.lineTo(x + hw, y - hw);
           ctx.lineTo(x + s, y - hw);
           ctx.lineTo(x + s, y + hw);
           ctx.lineTo(x + hw, y + hw);
           ctx.lineTo(x + hw, y + s);
           ctx.lineTo(x - hw, y + s);
           ctx.lineTo(x - hw, y + hw);
           ctx.lineTo(x - s, y + hw);
           ctx.lineTo(x - s, y - hw);
           ctx.closePath();
           ctx.fill()
        }

        function drawCorner(x, y, dx, dy, s, w) { // draw crosshair s is size, w is width
           // dx and dy are directions        
           const hw = w / 2; // half width
           ctx.beginPath();
           ctx.lineTo(x, y);
           ctx.lineTo(x + dx * s, y);
           ctx.lineTo(x + dx * s, y + dy * w);
           ctx.lineTo(x + dx * w, y + dy * w);
           ctx.lineTo(x + dx * w, y + dy * s);
           ctx.lineTo(x, y + dy * s);
           ctx.closePath();
           ctx.fill();
        }
        ctx.fillStyle = fill;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
        ctx.fillStyle = detailCol;
        drawCross(x + w / 2, y + h / 2, crosshairSize, detailWidth);
        drawCorner(x, y, 1, 1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth);
        drawCorner(x + w, y, -1, 1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth);
        drawCorner(x + w, y + h, -1, -1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth);
        drawCorner(x, y + h, 1, -1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth); 
}` //end of function`



//calling drawBox function 
 drawBox(startposition.x, startposition.y, width * 2, height * 2, crosshairSize, 1, "#6E97B1", '#0055FE');
```

Answer (score 0):

I analyze those corners and came with this solution like I needed direction, which way I am dragging this rectangle. so, calculate direction like this

```
     directionX = previousMousePosition.x - startposition.x;
     directionY = previousMousePosition.y - startposition.y;
```

then apply some condition with the help of direction

```
 function drawCorner(x, y, dx, dy, s, w) { // draw crosshair s is size, w is width

        // dx and dy are directions        
        const hw = w / 2; // half width
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + dx * s, y);
        ctx.lineTo(x + dx * s, y + dy * w);
        ctx.lineTo(x + dx * w, y + dy * w);
        ctx.lineTo(x + dx * w, y + dy * s);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y + dy * s);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

     }

     var crosshairSize = 10;
     var detailWidth = 2;
     if (directionY > 0 && directionX > 0)    // down
     {
        drawCorner(startposition.x, startposition.y, 1, 1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth);    //1
        drawCorner(startposition.x + directionY , startposition.y, -1, 1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth); //2
        drawCorner(startposition.x + directionY , startposition.y + directionX , -1, -1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth);    //3
        drawCorner(startposition.x, startposition.y + directionX , 1, -1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth);    //4
     }
     if (directionY < 0 && directionX > 0) {     // up

        drawCorner(startposition.x, startposition.y + directionY , 1, 1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth);    //1
        drawCorner(startposition.x + directionX , startposition.y + directionY , -1, 1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth); //2   
        drawCorner(startposition.x + directionX , startposition.y, -1, -1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth);    //3
        drawCorner(startposition.x, startposition.y, 1, -1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth);    //4
     }
     if (directionY > 0 && directionX < 0) {   //left

        drawCorner(startposition.x + directionX , startposition.y, 1, 1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth);    //1  
        drawCorner(startposition.x, startposition.y, -1, 1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth); //2
        drawCorner(startposition.x, startposition.y + directionY , -1, -1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth);    //3 
        drawCorner(startposition.x + directionX , startposition.y + directionY , 1, -1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth);    //4
     }

     if (directionY < 0 && directionX < 0) {   // upper left

        drawCorner(startposition.x + directionX , startposition.y + directionY , 1, 1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth);    //1   
        drawCorner(startposition.x, startposition.y + directionY , -1, 1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth); //2   
        drawCorner(startposition.x, startposition.y, -1, -1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth);    //3   
        drawCorner(startposition.x + directionX , startposition.y, 1, -1, crosshairSize * 2, detailWidth);    //4
     }
```